electron ^30.0.3 with reactjs | ipcRenderer not working on mac M1
Hi i am new to electron,
electron ipcRenderer not working on mac M1.
preload.js
const { ipcRenderer, contextBridge } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
  notificationApi: {
    sendNotification(message) {
      ipcRenderer.send('notify', message);
    }
  }
})

main.js
const { BrowserWindow, app, ipcMain, Notification } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: true,
      worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true,
      contextIsolation: true
    }
  })
  win.loadFile('index.html');
  win.webContents.openDevTools();
}

  require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {
    electron: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', '.bin', 'electron')
  })


ipcMain.on('notify', (_, message) => {
  new Notification({title: 'Notification', body: message}).show(); //calling
})


app.whenReady().then( () => {
    createWindow()
} )

Error in console

[65486:0513/222624.486948:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "Request Autofill.enable
failed. {"code":-32601,"message":"'Autofill.enable' wasn't found"}",
source:
devtools://devtools/bundled/core/protocol_client/protocol_client.js
(1)


The "error" you shared has nothing to do with IPC. This is a known issue caused by the dev tools, with no current fix. See this response from one of Electron's developers. You need to share all the relevant information and code about what's "not working".

hi @Arkellys, thanks for response. i want to show notification on click button this is my click button code <button onClick={() => {
electron.notificationApi.sendNotification('My custom notification!');
}}>Notify, rest i have shared all code.
